# How to Get data from many-to-many relation in Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, many-to-many

I got 2 entities related to each other in a many-to-many relationship in my model.

There's just 2 tables I know that in the db there are 3 tables in SQL I may try something like this.

```
select * 
from table1 
where table1.id in (select idTable1 from middleTable)
```

How can I do this using Entity Framework and Linq?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I Resolve my problem with something like this

```
 container.Table.Where(x=> x.TableRealed.any(y=> x.column == value)).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're letting the Entity Designer generate your model for you, it can "hide" the "middle table" of many-to-many relationships, as long as that middle table contains nothing but the ids of the two tables that have the relationship (and those ids are primary keys).

Once the model has been generated, you will have collection properties on both "sides" of the relationship. For example, I have two tables, People and Houses, they have a many-to-many relationship. If I've set everything up correctly, each `Person` object will have a property `Houses` and each `House` object will have a property `People`.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: so you say if I have a house then I got the all person are related to the house?

Comment: according to you example I'm looking all house that has people. how can I do this using entity and linq?